# how to apply java plugin too all projects except one special projects?

Tags: gradle

If I have a multiple projects in gradle, there are project1 .. project10. And all depends on java plugin except project10. How to do that?

I am planning to use subprojects but then it will apply to project10 as well. so how exclude it?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Haven't tested it but seems like you will be able to filter by name:

[Subproject configuration](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:subproject_configuration) - base on the **Filtering by name** section, you should be able to do something like this.

```
configure(subprojects.findAll {it.name != 'project10'}) {
    apply plugin: 'java'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Except several projects:

```
configure(subprojects.findAll {
    !listOf("project2", "project5").contains(it.name)
}) {
    apply plugin: 'java'
}
```

On Kotlin DSL:

```
configure(subprojects.filter {
    !listOf("project2", "project5").contains(it.name)
}) {
    apply(plugin = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.spring")
}
```